# use id from feature as geopandas dataframe index

Tags: python, indexing, geojson, geopandas

What I am trying to achieve is turning a geojson file into GeoDataFrame while moving feature "id" into an index. Example code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import json

data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
  {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-1, -1], [0, 1], [1, 1], [-1, -1]], "type": "LineString"}, "id": 123, "properties": {"building": "house"}, "type": "Feature"},
  {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-2, -2], [0, 2], [2, 2], [-2, -2]], "type": "LineString"}, "id": 456, "properties": {"building": "apartments"}, "type": "Feature"}
]}

with open('/tmp/foo.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(data, f)

gpd.read_file('/tmp/foo.json')
```

The problem is that the ids are simply thrown away and instead it uses auto-incrementing `RangeIndex`.

```
     building                                           geometry
0       house  LINESTRING (-1.00000 -1.00000, 0.00000 1.00000...
1  apartments  LINESTRING (-2.00000 -2.00000, 0.00000 2.00000...
```

Could you please advise how to solve this situation in an elegant manner? Should I just collect the ids and set the index manually like so:

```
gdf.index = [x['id'] for x in data['features']]
```

Comment: geopandas uses [fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html) to read GeoJSON under the hood. You could open the file with fiona and read the IDs from each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **pandas** `json_normalize()` to extract from the *geojson* and `set_index()` to set it.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import pandas as pd

data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
  {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-1, -1], [0, 1], [1, 1], [-1, -1]], "type": "LineString"}, "id": 123, "properties": {"building": "house"}, "type": "Feature"},
  {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-2, -2], [0, 2], [2, 2], [-2, -2]], "type": "LineString"}, "id": 456, "properties": {"building": "apartments"}, "type": "Feature"}
]}

gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data).set_index(pd.json_normalize(data["features"])["id"].values)
```

|  | geometry | building |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | LINESTRING (-1 -1, 0 1, 1 1, -1 -1) | house |
| 456 | LINESTRING (-2 -2, 0 2, 2 2, -2 -2) | apartments |

Comment: Thank you for your response. Note however that I want "ID" to appear in index and as soon as `gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data)` is called this information is discarded. The goal is to have a GeoDataFrame in which `gdf.index` returns `Int64Index([123, 456], dtype='int64')`.

Comment: ok -misread what you are trying to achieve.  updated

Comment: much appreciated!